# is there a way on adding two models properties inside ASP.NET View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have been trying to make this happen for a few hours now.I have two models within my model folder called Models, i am trying to pull data from the model to display it in the view, i am aware of only one model statement can be applied to the view. So i have Created a ViewModels which contain the properties that i would like to reference in the view. now when i run the the application im getting a compilation Error which says:

"Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Models' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I would appreciate a bit of help of if there is any other way of doing it feel free to advice.

> New ViewModel created

```
  public class MainModelscs <T> where T :class
{
    public StoreAudit StoreAudit { get; set; }
    public StoreQuestions StoreQuestions { get; set; }
    public List<string> StoreWindow { get; set; }

    public IPagedList<T> IndexList { get; set; }

}
```

ViewMode PROPERTIES inside my view,

```
@model PopMarketing.ViewModel.MainModelscs<PopMarketing.Models>
```

> Model 1

```
public class StoreQuestions
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }

    public int AuditId { get; set; }

    public int QuestionOne { get; set; }

    public string QuestionTwo { get; set; }
    public string QuestionThree { get; set; }
    public string QuestionFour { get; set; }

    }
```

Model 2

```
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AuditId { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public int StoreNumber { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
```

Controller Method

```
public class AuditController : Controller
{
    private PopMarketingContext db = new PopMarketingContext();

    //
    // GET: /Audit/

    private const string PASSWORD = "MarchJava2016";

    public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        int number;
        int check;
        bool result = Int32.TryParse(searchString, out number);

        if (result)
        {
            check = Convert.ToInt32(searchString);

            var shops = from s in db.StoreAudit
                        select s;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                shops = shops.Where(s => s.StoreName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) ||
                    s.StoreNumber.Equals(check));
            }

            return View(shops.ToList());
        }

        else
        {
            var shops = from s in db.StoreAudit
                        select s;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                shops = shops.Where(s => s.StoreName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }

            return View(shops.ToList());
        }


    }
```

Comment: Could you show your controller and the 2 models you want to (partially) combine in the view model?

Comment: whta is PopMarketing.Models, and what is the full namespace of Models?

Comment: You need to pass PopMarketing.Models.<ModelName> , you are passing namespace in @model PopMarketing.ViewModel.MainModelscs<PopMarketing.Models>

Comment: Create one more model which will be having all the desired fields you need to show and create view based on that.

Comment: @Devilscomrade I have updated my Post but for the record i have touched the controller since i have created the ViewModel

Comment: @Nirman PopMarketing is the name of the project and Models is the folder whoch contains all the models

Comment: @JaiminDave im trying to pass two models not just one what you suggesting is only for one model?

Comment: can you edit your code to include whole of the code in public class MainModelscs including the namespace declaration?

Comment: @It'satrap the post is all the the code for MainModelcs can you suggest anything that could be added

Comment: please show your folder structure and your code.

Comment: i want you to include the namespace declaration also. FYI from your title, i can understand your concern. In my website, i also wanted to display a page based on join of 2 tables, but a view can be based on only one model. So i just created another table "Join" with properties from both the models and written the ORM code to map the join to the "Join" table.

Comment: @It'satrap using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PopMarketing.Models                     Can you show me your "join"table and yor ORC code

Comment: @JaiminDave these are  all the codes i provided on my post and would you like me to include a image of my folder structure?

Comment: Sure i will add an answer in some time showing the relevant code. RIght now i am in office. So expect my answer in about 5 hours.

Comment: @It'satrap  sure thank you in advance

Comment: you are passing list of StoreAudit in view as model? you need to create one view model that contains all the properties and pass it to the view not the shops.ToList().

Comment: create instance of MainModelscs and pass it to the view. and in your view write 
@model PopMarketing.ViewModel.MainModelscs<ModelName>

Answer (score 0):

Jaimin is correct, in @model you pass the class you want to use as model, not the directory or namespace of the class.

As for using viewmodels correctly:

Let's say I have two classes:

```
class Student
{
public string name;
public string mentor;
}

class Teacher
{
public string name;
public string salary;
}
```

And i want to have a view show both their names. I can create a viewmodel like this:

```
class StudentAndTeacherVM
{
 public Teacher teacher;
 public Student student;
}
```

The controller would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 var student = new Student();
 *fill student*
 var teacher = new Teacher();
 *fill teacher*
var model = new PersonVM();
model.teacher = teacher;
model.student = student;
return view(model);
}
```

Now you can reach them in the view by:

@Model.student.name
@Model.teacher.name

Or if I want to be as efficient as possible, I could also just put in the names into the VM.

controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
var student = new Student();
*fill student*
var teacher = new Teacher();
*fill teacher*
var model = new PersonVM();
model.teacherName = teacher.name;
model.studentName= student.name;
return view(model);
}
```

View:

```
class StudentAndTeacherVM
{
public string teacherName;
public string studentName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create instance of MainModelscs  in your action

. . .

```
i.e. MainModelscs <string> Obj = new MainModelscs <string> ;
```

. . .

Then pass this to the view.

```
return View(Obj);
```

Now in your view,

```
@model PopMarketing.ViewModel.MainModelscs<string>
```

(take T as your model name not the namespace!)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i got much late than i said. But here is how you can join two tables, map them to a model and pass to the view. The first one of the class whose properties correspond to the comments table of the database.

```
public class Comments
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public int Upvote { get; set; }
    public int Downvote { get; set; }
    public int InappropriateFlags { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public int ReplyTo { get; set; }
    public bool replied { get; set; }
}
```

Now another user profiles table which is needed to be joined  with the comments table.

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int Reputation { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfRegistration { get; set; }
    public int Money { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int? PostalCode { get; set; }
    public int ProfileViews { get; set; }
    public string AboutMe { get; set; }
}
```

Now the much needed model for handling the join of these two tables. I haven't included all the properties of both tables as i didn't need them in the view, but you can ofcourse include them. In that case, don't forget to update your data access query also.

```
public class CommentUserProfileJoin
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int Upvote { get; set; }
    public int Downvote { get; set; }
    public int InappropriateFlags { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public int ReplyTo { get; set; }
    public bool replied { get; set; }
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

I am using dapper ORM. So this is the data access code that creates a join and maps it to the join table written above.

```
public IEnumerable<CommentUserProfileJoin > GetComments(int postId, string controllerName, int replyTo)
    {
        IEnumerable<CommentUserProfileJoin> comments;
        const string query = "Select c.[id], c.[CommentText], c.[Username], c.[Upvote], c.[Downvote], c.[InappropriateFlags], c.[PostId], c.[ControllerName], c.[ReplyTo], c.[replied], u.[id] as UserProfileId, u.displayname from Main.Comments c LEFT JOIN Profile.UserProfiles u on c.username = u.username where c.PostId = @postId and c.ControllerName = @contName and c.ReplyTo = @ReplyTo order by ID desc";
        comments = conObj.Query<CommentUserProfileJoin>(query, new { postId = postId, contName = controllerName, ReplyTo = replyTo });
        return comments;
    }
```

so now i have the model for the join of two tables, i can use it in any view like this

```
@model IEnumerable<DataAccessLayer.Models.CommentUserProfileJoin>
```

Hope this helps you. Also, unintentionally, i may not have followed best practices. I will be glad if someone can notify them through comments. Thanks